Path to wallpaper is not displayed anymore on Sequoia
I configured my Mac to show different wallpapers on each MacOS Space.
Until now, I had the path to the wallpaper shown on the screen as well. I had done this by setting
defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;killall Dock

However, since my update to MacOS 15.1, the path is not shown anymore, even after re-issuing the defaults write ... command.
Any idea of what I could do to find out the path to the wallpaper in a certain MacOS Space?
Note that
defaults read com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text

displays 1, from which I conclude that the value was indeed set correctly. It just seems that Sequoia ignores it.

"... on each MacOS Space" No idea what a "Space" is, but this is how I keep up with the "Wallpaper path": 1st: there isn't a single path, there are many paths. You can add paths by right-clicking a desktop, and selecting Change wallpaper.... 2nd That brings up a dialog with an Add folder button at the bottom. IOW, put your wallpapers where it makes sense to you & tell yr mac where to find them.

@Seamus - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac

@SteveM: Thanks :)  IOW, "spaces" = desktops. How very chic of Apple  :P

@Seamus: I know how to add pathes. This is not my question. I have my wallpapers on my spaces. To be more precise: For each space, I choose a directory with the wallpapers for this space, and then set the display to "random", so that the wallpaper is selcted randomly from this directory.

Hmmm.... I'm wondering why someone downvoted my question. It seems to be on topic, and I think all necessary information is provided. If you downvote, let me know at least what is missing!

After I have crossposted my question on a apple support forum, I got an explanation:
The feature to reveal the path of the displayed wallpaper has simply been removed in Sequoia.
From discussing the issue with a developer who has some knowledge in the handling of wallpapers and the way Spaces are implemented on Mac. According to him, there is no (documented) way to find out the wallpaper of a certain Space, if the Spaces are configured in a way that each Space gets for its wallpapers a different directory, and is supposed to randomly choose a file from this directory to show the backdrop picture for this space.
Hence, the "answer" is: It can't be done on Sequoia.
